# Does this run into undefined behavior regarding object lifetimes?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

```
#include "stdio.h"

class C {
 public:
  ~C() { printf("~C\n"); }
};

int I(const C& c) { printf("I\n"); return 0; }
void V(int i) { printf("V\n"); }

int main() {
  V(I(C()));
  return 0;
}
```

Seen output:

```
I
V
~C
```

what I would have expected:

```
I
~C
V
```

Comment: Why would you expect that?  What if I() returned const C&?  The lifetime of a temporary must last at least the duration of the expression it is embedded in.

Comment: @mcmcc: the expression that `C()` is embedded in is `I(C())`. The full line is an expression *statement*.

Comment: See the updated answer. Now its fully correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
V(I(C()));
```

`C()` creates a temporary which persists **till the completion of the full expression**, and the completion of the **full** expression is `;` (i.e the semicolon). That is why you see that output which is in my opinion is well-defined.

Section §12.2/3 from the Standard reads,

> [...] Temporary objects are **destroyed as the last step in evaluating
>   the full-expression** (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.

Just to emphasize, in this example the lifetime of the temporary has nothing to do with the *reference*  or *const reference*  parameter of function `I()`. Even if the signature of `I()` is:

```
int I(C c); //instead of : int I(const C & c);
```

the temporary would persist till the completion of the **full** expression and you would see *exactly* the same output.

See this: http://www.ideone.com/RYWhy

Answer (score 3):

The call to `V` returns before the full expression has been completely evaluated. And when `V` has returned, it will have printed its stuff (there is a sequence point before returning from `V`).

The temporary `C()` is only destroyed after the complete full expression has been evaluated.

Comment: So, in effect, the lifetime of a temporary is  the extent of all enclosing expressions, rather than just the directly enclosing one (in this case `I(C())`)?

Comment: @BCS: Yes. See my post and the quotation from the Standard. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz your answer says that the lifetime is as long as until the full-expression end because it's bound to a reference. But it doesn't really have to do with a reference. The temporary will live until the end of the full expression independent of any references.

Comment: @Johannes: But the Standard says it has to do with reference. :-/

Comment: @BCS, yes. "full expression" means the whole lexical expression, including any "invisible" constructor call and implicit conversions that would take the result of such an expression.

Comment: @Nawaz the spec says about temporaries in general "Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.". It just has that statement about references because before it, it says "The temporary to which the reference is
bound [...] persists for the lifetime of the reference except as specified below.", and the text you quoted is such an exception. So even if you would pass the address of the temporary as a pointer (like, `C().getThisPtr()`), it would still be safe.

Comment: @Johannes: Yeah. I also found that. I updated my post with few more edits and emphasizes. Thanks for pointing out that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why? The temporary lives till the end of the full expression.

Comment: If the temporary could be legally destroyed after evaluating only the directly containing expression, then that stack space could be used for evaluating the remainder of the expression. Given the historically lax rules about expression evaluation, it seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is the one mandated by the standard: temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression creating them.

Historically another behavior was seen (and is still available in some compilers): destruction at the end of the block.  In your case it wouldn't have made a difference as it delays still further the destruction.